# Setting delegate breaks webview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just added this line of code in my view did load: `myWebView.delegate = self;` as well as the delegate in the .h file, but now after setting the delegate, no web page loads, but it did before.

Comment: can you comment this line and run your project and let us know if it works?

Comment: the line does run

Comment: Which delegate methods have you implemented. And `the line does run` means you can see the web pages ?

Comment: I implemented WebViewDelegate and I mean it sets the delegate but I can't see anything

Comment: I was saying if you uncomment this line `myWebView.delegate = self;` then are your web page are loading?

Comment: It was never a comment but if I comment it, my web pages load but if I uncomment they don't

Comment: Can your show what have your written in your delegate method. Just post the implementation in question. Then we'll be able to help you

Comment: I'll have to edit it later - I have to go

Comment: In ViewController.h, I have `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>` and in the ViewController.m in the `viewDidLoad`,  doing `self.webView.delgate = self` returns as an error, so I know that because that error, its not running, also I have a  `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method but that never runs, so I know it’s also not connected, and with my current code: `webView.delegate = self` causes the page to not load.

Comment: By error you mean compile time error?

Comment: No, immediate error